# Seeking a system for Baratza Encore clean-up in low humidity

Tags: grinder, cleaning

I have a Baratza Encore and really love using it when I can.  The biggest problem I have is what happens after I'm done using it when the air is dry and static is more common.

When I grind, I take the grounds bin out and dump the grounds into my (aeropress/french press/bonavita), but there's always a bit of leftover grounds clung to it due to static electricity.  Here's where I get stuck with seemingly only bad choices:

1. If I rinse the bin, I don't want to put it back in wet, so I leave it to dry. As soon as I move the grinder or even bump it, some grounds drop out and make a bit of a mess
2. If I don't rinse the bin and just put it back, stale grounds are in there the next time I want to grind
3. If I try to wipe the bin, the grounds tend to make a mess anyway since they behave unpredictably due to static

Is there some better approach or system I can use that reduces the mess without compromising the quality of my brew?

Comment: Have you tried [this technique](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/5439)? It's possibly a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moistening the environment using one of the techniques in this [related answer](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/capresso-static-effects-on-grounds/) will solve the issue of the grinds sticking to the bin.  The first and simplest approach to try is to add a few drops of water to the beans.